# How can I call a post ID from a Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I would like to do is call a certain post ID:

[image]

depending on what cell is tapped on a UITableView and display data from it on a different ViewController. Currently, each post has a different ID along with data shown in the photo above

I have seen this method used to call a username based on an ID:

```
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.userLabel.text = dictionary["username"] as? String
            }
        })
```

Would this be possible to do this with a post ID like shown in the screenshot above? If so, what would be the simplest way to do that?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: From my knowledge, I don't think you can. My solution is to add that ID inside your branch.

Comment: @cyril-ivar-garcia Could you explain to me on how I could accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: @gabe show a snippet of your code on how you add data to your firebase database, and I'll use that to help you out.

Comment: Here (http://pastebin.com/aEzNPbYa) is a paste of how I currently create and display data from Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I simplified the code just so I can explain it easier.

First create a variable outside your methods called `postID` and set this equal to FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoID()

`let postID = UUID().uuidString`

then inside your postObject add another set and set the variable youve declared earlier `"postID": postID`

```
let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                                "uid": uid,
                                                "title": title,
                                                "price": price,
                                                "rating": rating,
                                                "description": description,
                                                "username" : username,
                                                "image": self.imageFileName,
                                                "postID": self.postID
                                            ]
```

Finally replace  `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoID().setValue(postObject)`

with  `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.postID).setValue(postObject)`

Comment: I get the error 'Expression type 'Void' (aka '()') is ambiguous without more context' when using `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postID).setValue(postObject)`

Comment: So instead of `let postID = FIRDatabase.database().reference.childByAutoID()` replace it with `let postID = UUID().uuidString`

Comment: That worked. The only thing I needed to add was 'self.' before postID and everything worked great.

Comment: Yea, so instead of `childByAutoID` which is just a random ID generated by firebase, I manually create a random ID with `UUID`. Basically does what you are looking for. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation similar to yours.  Another way you can do this is by getting the postID from the dictionary key.

This example would get all of the postIDs, but that's a starting point.

```
            let json = JSON(value)
                let keys = value.keys
                for element in keys {
                    var postID = ""
                    for key in keys {
                        if element == key {
                            postID = key
                        }
                    }
```